# Discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice. error when connected to voice

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I hate to sound stupid on this (I probably do to some) I'm truly trying my best. I have been having issues with d.py voice. I have a bot with music bot functionality, and when I try to run the command `k!play (song name)` It fails saying it is not connected to the voice, when it is connected on the client side, and the code side. I don't understand what's going on. Here's the code for the whole command, and the whole error log under that:

```
@client.command(aliases=['p'])
async def play(ctx, *, query: t.Optional[str]):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")

    except PermissionError:
        return


    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice is None:
        voiceChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await voiceChannel.connect()
        print("Connected to voice")
        voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    spotify_regex1 = r"https://open.spotify.com/track/(......................)"
    spotify_regex2 = r"https://open.spotify.com/track/(.......................)(si=)(................)"

    match = re.match(spotify_regex1, query)
    is_match1 = bool(match)
    match = re.match(spotify_regex2, query)
    is_match2 = bool(match)

    if is_match1 or is_match2 is True:
        print("Trying With Spotify")
        os.system(f"spotdl '{query}'")
        await ctx.send(f"`Now Playing:`  {query}")


    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio',
        'restrictfilenames': False,
        'noplaylist': True,
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
    }

    try:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([query])
            query_id = os.popen(f'youtube-dl --get-id "ytsearch:{query}"').read()
            title = os.popen(f'youtube-dl --get-title "ytsearch:{query_id}"').read()
            thumbnail_embed = os.popen(f'youtube-dl --get-thumbnail "ytsearch:{query_id}"').read()
            duration_embed = os.popen(f'youtube-dl --get-duration "ytsearch:{query_id}"').read()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Now Playing", color=0xa00000)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail_embed)
            embed.add_field(name=title, value=f"`0:00 / {duration_embed}`", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.message.author}")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    except:
        return

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
            print("Changed mp3 to mp3")

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".m4a"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
            print("Changed m4a to mp3")

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".webm"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
            print("Changed webm to mp3")

    if song_there is False:
        time.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send("Song not found!")

    print("Playing File (or trying to)")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.80
```

```
Connected to voice
[download] Downloading playlist: fuwa fuwa time
[youtube:search] query "fuwa fuwa time": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist fuwa fuwa time: Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] jL8p9vteR5g: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video jL8p9vteR5g because of --no-playlist
[youtube] jL8p9vteR5g: Downloading player f1ca6900
[download] Destination: K-ON! Fuwa Fuwa Time Yui and Mio Duet HD-jL8p9vteR5g.m4a
[download] 100% of 3.71MiB in 01:05                 
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "K-ON! Fuwa Fuwa Time Yui and Mio Duet HD-jL8p9vteR5g.m4a"
[download] Finished downloading playlist: fuwa fuwa time
Changed m4a to mp3
Playing File (or trying to)
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\kyoko test\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users..\PycharmProjects\kyoko test\main.py", line 850, in play
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\kyoko test\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 555, in play
    raise ClientException('Not connected to voice.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\kyoko test\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 940, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\kyoko test\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\..\PycharmProjects\kyoko test\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.
```

Than thats the error log

Comment: Hey buddy, so your coming up one step short to find the actual error. The command invoke error exception is letting you know there was an error SOMEWHERE in your command code but doesn't specify what that error is (This is why CommandInvokeError has an attribute "Original" for the original execption) Can you be able to update your question with command decorator for play, and all of the following code? This error might not have anything to do with playing the music and could be something simple, but until you pull that "original" attribute your guess of what is going wrong is as good as ours.

Comment: I've updated the post! @Oddity

Answer (score 0):

This line of code could be the issue:

```
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)
```

Try this for getting the voice client:

```
voice = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
```

I am not entirely sure if this the issue but hopefully works. Oh also make sure that you are in a voice channel while running the command.

Comment: Can you tell me which part of the code should be replaced? this function is defined many times in different parameters, your also changing it to be called `voice_channel` which is confusing. @Roopesh-J

Comment: Ah sorry about the changing the variable name, lemme edit that. Well first make sure that you trying to run the `play` command while you are also in the voice channel. Don't replace the code but just add the line I suggested under your line that I mentioned. It is basically just a different way of getting the voice client, so I thought may this way it would work.

Comment: I did that and it still gave me the error, and yes I am in a vc, I tested it and If i wasn't it would give me a "User is not in vc" error.

Comment: Dang, that's really weird. I don't know what else could be the issue. I would recommend maybe creating another command that just connects the bot to the voice channel, since you can just visually check if the bot is in the channel or not.

Comment: This is the code I used from an older bot: 
`voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='General')`. `await voiceChannel.connect()`. I only used it in my general channel so I just straight up hardcoded the name. Maybe it will help though.

Comment: I used to use that exact code, but I changed it to be any vc just for accessibility, I'll try to see if that works. (Update: It still dosent! I dont understand whats going on as I have never gotten this error.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239518/discussion-between-roopesh-j-and-jacob-shankman).